# jQuery Tabbing Order

Tags: jquery, html, tabbing

With the absolute positioning of my submit button, when I tab on the last text box, it jumps over the button.  Is it possible to intercept the tab event and place focus on my submit button when my last text box loses focus?

Comment: See the answer b y RHicke. This would be the preferred method, but might not fit all circumstances.  If this does not resolve the issue, post a comment and I can provide a mechanism to intercept the tab key (or any others).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the tabindex html attribute to specify the order of tab operations on a page.